# Arduino & SeeedStudio CAN-BUS Shield

Tags: arduino, can-bus

I have connected my CAN-BUS shield to my heating systems and I'm getting data from the bus.
This is working (I think).
However, I can not get the data that I want.
Please see attached pictures.

[CAN-open data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KNdCJ.jpg)

[CAN-Bus Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o36C5.jpg)

It says that it's running with CAN open and the node should be 80 (0X50 hex).
However when I put a filter on that only shows data from node 80 I'll not get get any data.
Also when I try without filter, I'll not get any data from the module!

It also says the it is sending a heartbeat every 1s. and this one I have found on Node id 1862 (0X746 hex).

How can I read data from the module.

Code to read from the shield:

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include "mcp_can.h"

INT32U canId = 0x000;
MCP_CAN CAN(9); 

unsigned char len = 0;
unsigned char buf[11];
char str[40];


void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(38400);

START_INIT:

    if(CAN_OK == CAN.begin(CAN_125KBPS))
    {
        Serial.println("CAN BUS Shield init ok!");
    }
    else
    {
        Serial.println("CAN BUS Shield init fail");
        Serial.println("Init CAN BUS Shield again");
        delay(100);
        goto START_INIT;
    }
}


void loop()
{
    if(CAN_MSGAVAIL == CAN.checkReceive())  
      {
        CAN.readMsgBuf(&len, buf); 
        canId = CAN.getCanId();

               Serial.print("<");
              Serial.print(canId);
              for(int i = 0; i<len; i++)
                {
                  Serial.print(",");
                  Serial.print(buf[i]);
                }
            Serial.print(">");
            Serial.println();
      }
}
```

Comment: Labels and `goto` do have their place. Using them instead of loops is not such a place.

Comment: Sorry, Joachim
I'm not quite sure what you're talking about!

Comment: It's unrelated to your question, but don't use `goto` as a way to implement loops.

Comment: Anyone else that can help???

Answer (score 0):

The code is correct but there is one possible problem with the **mcp_can** library and compatible shields. The original Seed-Studio shield use 16 MHz crystal but there are other compatible modules on the market and not all of them use 16 MHz crystal, some use 8 Mhz instead.

Therefore first check the CAN module you want to use and in case it runs on 8 MHz you have to adjust the speed setting in the initialization. In such a case if you need to read CAN messages from a CAN bus running on 125 kb/s you have to set **CAN.begin(CAN_250KBPS)** in the initialization:

```
...
   if(CAN_OK == CAN.begin(CAN_250KBPS))
...
```

Check if you have CAN HI and CAN LO connected properly. This can be another problem.
Check if your SPI_CS_PIN is set correctly (in your scetch is CS on pin 9).

Then you should check your connection/speed/CS by sending a CAN message on the bus - the message has to be catched by your CAN bus sniffer.